# Declaration of Stage::add() must be compatible with TherapyElement::add(TherapyElement $TA)

Tags: php, oop

I have abstract class TherapyElement with method Crate(TherapyElement $te). I have 3 more classes(Training, Stage, Phase) that extends TherapyElement. And  I want to emplement method "add()" next way:
Training:

```
public function add(Stage $stage ) {
   ...     
}
```

Stage:

```
public function add(Phase $stage ) {
        ...
}
```

Phase:

```
public function add(Phase $stage ) {
       .. 
}
```

But i got error Declaration of Stage::add() must be compatible with TherapyElement::add(TherapyElement $TA). I thought if Training, Stage, Phase extends TherapyElement so they are instanceof TherapyElement and can be use as param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the argument name must be the same. In the base `TherapyElement` class you called the argument `$TA`, whereas in the others you called it `$stage`.

Change them all to `$TA` or `$stage`, instead of interchanging them.